# Пройти авторизацию на госуслугах из скрипта

Tags: python, http, curl

Есть задача: нужно из скрипта авторизацию на госуслугах как организация, получить `marker`, чтобы его приложить к запросам в другой гос. информационной системе для подачи в неё информации и документов.
Вообще самма регичтрация не выглядит сложной: отправляем запрос на адрес https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/idp/login/pwd/do
с параметрами:

```
'command': '',
'idType': 'phone',
'login': '+7(999)9999999',
'mobileOrEmail': '+7+999+9999999',
'password': '123456789',
'snils': ''
```

Вот этот самый `command` и не понятен, откуда оно его берёт. Понятно, что оно зависит от времени, закодировано в `base64`.

При раскодировке получается `{"typ":"JWT","kid":"lgn_ctx","alg":"HS256"}`+ некоторая абракадабра. Абракадабра меняется. Если взять абракадабру из браузера - авторизация не проходит. Если вовсе не передавать этот параметр - авторизация не проходит(

Вот на этом и стопор. Дальше - понятнее - нужно сделать `get`, на то, какие организации привязаны к пользователю, взять id организации и сделать запрос с id организации - по идее после этого должно выдать от самый `marker`.

Есть описание, в котором пользователю нужно показать страницу свой ИС, потом сделать редирект на госуслуги, там подождать пока авторизуется, потом редирект обратно, чтобы пользователь нажал 1 кнопку. Это муторно. Нужно оптимизировать и входить автоматически под логином/паролем, которые записаны у пользователя в локальной ИС, для входа в гос ИС. Тем более, что там после входа нужно передать море данных, а при помощи php ждать это или поддерживать как-то не очень. В планах взять python, и сделать всё при помощи requests и json.

Никто не пытался такое провернуть?
Может есть идеи как понять, что за переменная абракадабра в `command`, чтобы можно было её корректно сформировать и таки авторизоваться?

Comment: Это [JSON Web Token](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token). typ -- это тип токена (в данном случае JWT), alg -- алгоритм шифрования, kid -- уникальный идентификатор используемого ключа. [Здесь](https://habr.com/post/340146/) ещё можно почитать про JWT.

Comment: Ага, прочитал. Там всё таки 3 части:
`{"typ":"JWT","kid":"lgn_ctx","alg":"HS256"}.{"method":"pwd","attempts":0}.signature`.
Заголовок- понятно. Метод - понятно, попытки:0 - понятно.
В сигнатуре хэш первых 2-х частей, зашифрованный ключом. Что есть ключ....?

Comment: Если оно генерирует ключ у себя, подписывает токен, потом его передаёт себе же в другую страницу - то, видимо не получится из скрипта просто взять и авторизоваться.

Comment: Как запасной вариант - есть идея взять маркер из авторизации в системе через браузер, и подкинуть его в скрипт, в дальнейшем выполнять скрипт каждый час и обновлять маркер уже в системе, дабы есть такая возможность. Но вариант дурацкий.

Comment: у кого-то получилось залогиниться скриптом на ESIA?

Answer (score 2):

Авторизоваться в ЕСИА своим скриптом практически нереально. Там тонны обфусцированного жаваскрипта, который крутит, вертит и запутать хочет.

Самый простой, опробованный и успешный способ с помощью Python - это использовать selenium и chrome в режиме headless для выполнения автоматизированного заполнения и отправки формы авторизации, а затем стянуть cookies и использовать их уже в обычных запросах средствами python requests.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://esia.gosuslugi.ru")

login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mobileOrEmail")
passd = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
enter = driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginByPwdButton")

login.send_keys("aaa@bbb.com")
passd.send_keys("password")
enter.click()

driver.get_cookies()
```

Answer (score 1):

В гос.услугах есть другое api на запрос который дает этот самый command
Вот ссылка на неё https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/idp/login/pwd/switch
Ответ приходит в виде json
Запрос в неё делается в виде ajax, поэтому заголовок запроса должен содержать X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Извините, а какой смысл вы заложили в эту фразу - "api на запрос который дает этот самый command"?

Comment: смысл?! Смысл в том, чтобы делать запрос на эту ссылку и получить ответ в виде той самой command